# Redirect to a specific view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, navigation, segue

Just Have an issue and a "miss" in my programming "capacity".
I've got a tableview controller with some data parsed from a json.
When you choose a "news" you to to the detail view with all data in it.

Everything is ok, but I add a "check" If you are logged or not.
And if not you are "redirected" to login screen.

I try to do it with a segue (modal). It's working, but when I do it, my "navigation" is broken, like if he "lost" he's path.

[image: Storyboard]

I try to do it programatically like :

```
LoginViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

But when I'm doing it like that, nothing happen, my "detail view controller" load without redirecting

and got that log:

> nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar Finishing
>   up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar
>   subview tree might get corrupted.

Did someone have a hint for me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the normal way to do it. You would normally present that login view controller modally.

If this is just the way you want it you could do it using the following steps:

1) Connect your DetailViewController to your TableViewController (not from cell itself, but from that yellow icon which represents your ViewController at the bottom black bar). Choose push if you like and add the identifier to that Segue (for example, "DetailSegue")

2) Connect your LoginViewController to your TableViewController just like you connected your DetailViewController and add the identifier to that segue (for example, "LoginSegue").

Now, when the user clicks on some cell, you wish to check if session is still active, if it is you will do `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailSegue" sender:self];`, and if it is not, you will do `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:self];`

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks I did the trick !
Just have to take a look why my status bar disapear on "detail view" but seem to be easy / doable easily.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it all wrong. you need to study the very basic of seque programming (storyboard).
[follow this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

```
LoginViewController *controller = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

in storyboard you already have a push segue, & again you are pushing loginviewcontroller. thats why you are getting "nested push animation" warning.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty tough to understand what you want to do, the question isn't too clear.

If you want to link to a scene in your storyboard though, create a segue to this by ctrl + click & drag from the initial scene, then give the segue an ID (do this by clicking on the segue and using inspector to set an ID)

then in your tableview controller, where ever you are picking up your tab (assuming this is in the tableview delegate method) you can call the segue programatically

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOURSEGUEID" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did soemthing like that